# Replace text numbers as file name in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I need to replace some numbers contained in my text with the file name number, example:

Filename: text-3.txt

1. Text bla bla bla, aaaa ...

Replace that number "1." by the number 3, contained in the file name. And also remove that "." that stayed.

Comment: Is this for one file or for many? Are you open to using powershell?

Comment: You can't really do this with notepad++ alone.

Comment: It is for many files, and also in subdirectories, and yes I can use PowerShell and anothers programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together this powershell for you. What is happening is described in the comments I've added. Comments begin with a "#". If your filesname conventions are different than your example of 'text-1.txt' then you will have to modify this line to the appropriate name conventions `$target_files = gci $working_dir\* -include 'text*.txt'` -specifically what is inside the `-include` argument.

Just update that if needed and the `$working_dir` variable in this script to fit the directory you're working with.

```
# where to look for files
    $working_dir = "C:\Users\userNameHere\Desktop\Folder123"
# Find the files with get-childitem, put into variable.
    $target_files = gci $working_dir\* -include 'text*.txt'


# For every file, do the following
foreach($file in $target_files){
    # Read the file content with get-content
        $file_content = gc $file -raw
    # Create regex pattern to find the number for replacing
        $reg_pattern = '^.*\d+[.]'
    # Get the number out of the filename. 
        $file.Name -match "\d+" | Out-null
    [int]$file_number = $matches[0]


    # If we find a Number followed by a period in the content, replace it with the number we found in the filename
        if($file_content -match $reg_pattern){
           $file_content -replace $matches[0],$file_number | sc $file
        }

}
```

Paste this into a notepad, do file> save as> and change the dropdown for "Filetype" to say `All Files (*.*)`. Type in what you will name the script followed by a `.ps1` file extention. This will save it as a powershell file. Then you'll right click that file and "Run with Powershell".

Comment: I'm  very glad it worked for you. Please remember to mark my solution as the answer to your question. :)